# How do I check if email address is used?

Tags: email, smtp, imap, pop3

Is there a legal way to check whether email address is actively used?
I've heard an email with, say, image can be sent and if the user opens an email there is a chance the image url will be accessed. Are there any other ways?

Comment: No, there is no reliable way to confirm that an e-mail has been received, let alone read. As you say, you can track certain things, but a lot of apps now specifically stop things being loaded for security making it somewhat meaningless from a statistics point of view (imo).

Comment: You can talk to the mail server directly and using the HELO, MAIL FROM and RCPT TO commands to determine if the user is there. But a number of servers will say that the user exists whether they really do or not (such as yahoo.com). As @JonStirling said, there is no reliable way to check. The process I've described also is only to determine if the email address exists, not whether it is active. Note that even if image processing worked, there's no guarantee the user wouldn't just delete the email without opening it.